# How to find a DOM element by part of its ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to find `<div id="sometrack123456"></div>` by part of its id  **"track"** using jQuery.

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the attribute contains selector `[attr*="str"]`

```
$('div[id*="track"]').doSomething();
```

The quote order is important.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('div[id*="track"]')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector.

```
$('div[id*="track"]')
```